# why the default implemention of CookieStore do not use a tree-like struct?

Tags: java, performance, cookies, cookiestore

InMemoryCookieStore is the default CookieStore of java , but the main store is a ArrayList, the add and remove op will cost O(n) in worst case ,and index is map , which scan the keySet in order to remove expired cookie. why it use tree(which can represent domain very well,like .b.com is the parent of .a.b.com ) and set (locate Cookie in constant time) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CookieStore has a method

```
List<HttpCookie> getCookies()
```

so it must maintain, or copy all the cookies on demand.  I assume they decided that maintaining a list was the most efficient.

Comment: maybe, but a set may be more efficient since add op invoke when every request coming in.

Comment: AFAIK All the List data types it uses could be changed to Set. I don't see a reason that order matters and it doesn't appear to allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you have so many cookies that O(n) is noticeably larger than O(1) in terms of performance? When choosing between sub-optimization and code manageability, most go for clean, manageable code.

Comment: agree, that why it just a default implemention . so i have to implement a more efficient for my web crawler ~

Comment: Well, go ahead and knock yourself out ;) IMO, it's a waste of time. The cost of parsing each cookie from the header is going to outweigh the cost of adding the Cookie to the CookieStore by many orders of magnitude, making your optimizations of the cookiestore completely unnoticeable in the overall execution time.